# How do I set an active tab for TabControl in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, tabs, firemonkey

I've made a `Form` with a `TabControl` and Four `TabItem` tabs on the `TabControl`. By default, the first tab is always the active tab:

[image: Python GUI App with four tabs]

```
self.TabControl1 = TabControl(self)
self.TabControl1.Parent = self
self.TabControl1.Align = "Client"

self.TabItem1 = TabItem(self.TabControl1)
self.TabItem1.Text = "My first tab"
self.TabItem1.Parent = self.TabControl1

self.TabItem2 = TabItem(self.TabControl1)
self.TabItem2.Text = "My second tab"
self.TabItem2.Parent = self.TabControl1

self.TabItem3 = TabItem(self.TabControl1)
self.TabItem3.Text = "My third tab"
self.TabItem3.Parent = self.TabControl1

self.TabItem4 = TabItem(self.TabControl1)
self.TabItem4.Text = "My fourth tab"
self.TabItem4.Parent = self.TabControl1
```

How do I set a different tab as the default tab? Like, let's say I want to set the third tab as active via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TabControl` component has an `ActiveTab` property which you can set equal to your `TabItem` to make it active.

So if you want to make your third tab as the default active tab, then add the following line of code at the end of your third tab creation code:

```
self.TabControl1.ActiveTab = self.TabItem3
```

Full `TabItem` creation code:

```
self.TabItem3 = TabItem(self.TabControl1)
self.TabItem3.Text = "My third tab"
self.TabItem3.Parent = self.TabControl1
self.TabControl1.ActiveTab = self.TabItem3 # Sets it as ActiveTab
```

Now if you open the app, your third tab will be set as active by default:
[image: Python GUI app with four tabs]